# Can someone help me get a general idea of what dart and angularDart is?

Tags: web, dart, angular-dart

I was going through the Dart documentation and i realised that Dart actually offers various functionalities for web, App development and developing servers. As per my understanding it is a language which can bind various features of web.
Is it like a complete package of webdevelopment?
And does angularDart mean i can write code in angular along with maintaining the connections between different Dart applications? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dart is a programming language that can compile to JavaScript to run in the browser.

Angular Dart is a flavor of Angular written in Dart.
Angular provides UI components with data-binding, routing, dependency injection and a set of Material Design components to make it easy to build Single Page Applications in Dart.